# Parsererror when binding value from REST service KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest, knockout.js

I am trying to bind a single text string to an `<input>`. The REST service return a simple text string embed in a JSON. The client retrieves the text string but I get `parsererror`. The ajax request fails but contain the text string `jq.responseText`.

What causes the error and how do I bind a single string (non-array) value from a REST service?

PS. I am using Oracle Jet framework which is build on KnouckoutJS, JQuery and some other JS libs.

header.html

```
<input type='text' data-bind="value:hello" />
```

header.js

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout' ], function (oj, ko) {
/**
 * The view model for the main content view template
 */
function headerContentViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.hello = ko.observable("local hello");


    this.getStatus = function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/clear-obs/service/application/hello",                
            success: function (data) {
                $.parseJSON(data);
                self.hello(data.message);
            },
            error: function (jq, st, error) {
                alert(jq.responseText);
            }
        });
    };
    self.getStatus();


}
return headerContentViewModel;

});
```

Text string

```
{
   "message": "Hello World from REST service"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `dataType: "json"` to the request?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error.

Comment: If you're using chrome, ope the Network tab and do your request, you should see your request appear in this tab, and it will be red if there's an error. Then click on the event and you should have more info.

Answer (score 0):

please convert text string to javascript json object in your ajax success and try,

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
self.hello(data.message);
```

let me know if that worked as expected.

Comment: The $.parseJSON(data) didn't help, I get the same error. The success part of function is never invoked.

Comment: is it possible to create a fiddle for the same.? so we can check the response text.

Comment: Would be difficult since the REST service is only localhost, I think?

Comment: Update my question with details, in case it could affect the result.

Comment: can you please change to var data = $.parseJSON(data); instead of $.parseJSON(data);